# Can't Pickle rest_framework.request.Request object

Tags: python, celery, pickle

I get an error when I pass a request object (from rest_framework) to a celery task queue :

```
EncodeError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I have checked and its the request object that's creating the problem. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A request object doesn't make sense to pickle. It represents a client that is connected to your web server and waiting for a response *now* -- you can't serialize it, write it out to a task queue (or a file, or whatever), and expect to be able to respond to it later from another machine.

If you need to save specific properties of the request -- like the HTTP headers, the URI, or POST parameters -- you will need to extract those from the request and serialize them separate from the rest of the request.